# XML with XSL generating hierarchical xml from flat xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create a hierarchical xml from a flat xml using xslt.

This is the XML file:

```
<Geo> 
   <Bean> 
       <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</LEVEL1> 
       <DESCRIPTION>Asia Pacific</DESCRIPTION> 
   <Bean> 
   <DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>India</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>India</DESCRIPTION> 
       <Bean> 
   <DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>India</LEVEL2> 
<LEVEL3>NewDelhi</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>India Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
   <Bean> 
<DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>China</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>China</DESCRIPTION> 
       <Bean> 
   <DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>China</LEVEL2> 
<LEVEL3>Hongkong</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
   <Bean> 
<Bean> 
       <LEVEL1>NorthAmerica</LEVEL1> 
       <DESCRIPTION>North America</DESCRIPTION> 
   <Bean> 
   <DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>NorthAmerica</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>WashingtonDC</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>capital</DESCRIPTION> 
       <Bean> 
   <DBBean> 
       <LEVEL1>NorthAmerica</LEVEL1> 
       <LEVEL2>Texas</LEVEL2> 
<LEVEL3>aBCD</LEVEL2> 
       <DESCRIPTION>Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
   <Bean> 
</Geo>
```

Output:

```
 <geo> 
    <LEVEL1>AsiaPacific</Level1> 
    <DESCRIPTION>Asia Pacific</DESCRIPTION> 
          <LEVEL2>India</Level2> 
          <DESCRIPTION>India</DESCRIPTION> 
                <LEVEL3>NewDelhi</Level2> 
                <DESCRIPTION>India Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
        <LEVEL2>China</Level2> 
        <DESCRIPTION>China</DESCRIPTION> 
               <LEVEL3>Honkong</Level3> 
              <DESCRIPTION>Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
    <LEVEL1>NorthAmerica</Level1> 
    <DESCRIPTION>NorthAmerica</LEVEL1> 
        <LEVEL2>WashingtonDC</Level3> 
        <DESCRIPTION>Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
             <LEVEL3>abCD</Level2> 
            <DESCRIPTION>Capital</DESCRIPTION> 
    </ge0>
```

I got stuck in middle of writing xslt logic while doing for each group, please advise on this. I tried transforming till level but later got struck. Is it OK to use keys or we should go for grouping?

Comment: Is there a known maximum number of LEVELs? -- Also, please fix the input so that it is well-formed XML. -- Note also that your output is indented incorrectly. I doubt you really want all those nodes to be siblings.

Comment: Please show what you tried already any what is missing with your attempt.

Comment: <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="LEVEL1">
        <Level1 lvl="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/><xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="LEVEL2">
               <Level2 lvl="{current-grouping-key()}">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="LEVEL3">
                     <Level3 lvl="{current-grouping-key()}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                     </Level3>

Comment: @user3912942 Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead.